# Alternative to Microsoft Security application block?

Tags: .net, security, application-blocks

We need to implement role-based security across our solution which has asp.net, winforms and web service entry points. We will also need some front end to configure it. I really don't feel like rolling my own,s I have done it a few times before and it is tedious.

I have historically not been a fan of the MS ABs because I found them to be over architected and inadequately unit-tested, but I haven't touched them for a few years.

Is the Security AB worth a look, or should I use an alternative? What would you recommend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is early days still, but I have now investigated both the Security AB and another solution called NetSqlAzMan. I found the latter to be vastly superior - in fact it is absolutely fantastic.

http://netsqlazman.codeplex.com/

EDIT: A year or two down the road now and we are tremendously happy with NetSqlAzMan.

Comment: are you still using netsqlazman, I am not able to use it as RolesProvider, get this error : 'Keyword not supported: 'storename'.